# MYSQL Left Join Not Working when Rows Not Found

Tags: mysql, left-join

I have created a MYSQL query that looks for users favorites and sorts the results based on their last time they viewed the page.

Everything works on the database call, except when the LEFT JOIN does not find results.

Let me show you some example queries

```
 EXPLAIN
 SELECT a.*,
        COUNT(b.SID) AS mcount,
   MAX(b.time) AS mtime
 FROM posts a
 LEFT JOIN impressions b ON a.SID = b.SID
 AND b.time > '1444679848'
 AND (b.MID = '3'
      OR b.FBID = '418'
      OR b.TID = '152')
 WHERE a.pending != 1
   AND a.sponsor != '1'
   AND a.fbpost = '0'
   AND a.roundup = '0'
   AND a.404 != '1'
   AND a.hide = '0'
   AND a.END >= '2015-10-22'
   AND a.added >= '2015-10-12'
   AND a.url_image > ''
   AND CHAR_LENGTH(a.states) < 80
   AND a.usa = '1'
 GROUP BY a.SID
 ORDER BY mcount DESC, (a.int_clicks + (a.int_views2b * 100)) DESC

 | id | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys                                                    | key          | key_len | ref                      | rows | Extra                                        |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+---------+--------------------------+------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | a     | range | end,added,usa,sponsor,pending                                    | added        | 4       | NULL                     | 2474 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | b     | ref   | MID,FBID,TID,SID                                                  | SID         | 5       | sp282q.a.SID             |  280 |                                              |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+---------+--------------------------+------+----------------------------------------------+
```

Here is the same query, but instead with invalid SID, FBID and TID numbers resulting in no matches

```
 EXPLAIN
 SELECT a.*,
        COUNT(b.SID) AS mcount,
        MAX(b.time) AS mtime
 FROM posts a
 LEFT JOIN impressions b ON a.SID = b.SID
 AND b.time > '1444679848'
 AND (b.MID = '3234234'
      OR b.FBID = '423423423418'
      OR b.TID = '152342342342')
 WHERE a.pending != 1
   AND a.sponsor != '1'
   AND a.fbpost = '0'
   AND a.roundup = '0'
   AND a.404 != '1'
   AND a.hide = '0'
   AND a.END >= '2015-10-22'
   AND a.added >= '2015-10-12'
   AND a.url_image > ''
   AND CHAR_LENGTH(a.states) < 80
   AND a.usa = '1'
 GROUP BY a.SID
 ORDER BY mcount DESC, (a.int_clicks + (a.int_views2b * 100)) DESC

 +----+-------------+-------+-------+------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+---------+------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
 | id | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys                                                    | key          | key_len | ref  | rows     | Extra                                        |
 +----+-------------+-------+-------+------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+---------+------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
 |  1 | SIMPLE      | a     | range | end,added,usa,sponsor,pending                                    | added        | 4       | NULL |     2474 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
 |  1 | SIMPLE      | b     | ALL   | MID,FBID,TID,SID                                                 | NULL         | NULL    | NULL | 13029182 | Using where                                  |
 +----+-------------+-------+-------+------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+---------+------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
```

For the second database call, when there are no MID, FBID or TID rows found, it returns the whole data base of over 13 million records.

When I switch these queries to an INNER JOIN, it will return the results fast when no records are found.

When I run the query with a LEFT JOIN, and no records are found, it locks mysql up and tries to run this query for hours.

What am I doing wrong here?

The expected output should be:

```
POSTID        mcount      COUNT ORDER    mtime
883             25             10        1444279848
823             22             22        1444249848
813             20             8         1444672448
816             6             18         1444672248
810             0             50         1444679848
811             0             45         1444479865
815             0             30         1444673468
```

The time column is the MAX(b.time) as mtime and COUNT ORDER is (a.int_clicks + (a.int_views2b * 100))

Updated with SHOW CREATE TABLE impressions

```
CREATE TABLE `impressions` (
    `id` int(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `SID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    `MID` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
    `FBID` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
    `TID` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
    `time` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
    `ip` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
    `data` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`),
    KEY `MID` (`MID`),
    KEY `FBID` (`FBID`),
    KEY `TID` (`TID`),
    KEY `SID` (`SID`),
    KEY `ip` (`ip`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=13029800 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 |
```

Comment: please use aliases a or b also for `WHERE` filters.

Comment: I have just tried to re-run the query with the alias in the WHERE clause and it still produces the same results. The only column names that match are the SID column.

Comment: I didn't ask for the aliases because I thought it would solve the problem. It may point the problem out, however, let me see. Edit: you didn't update your question. I need to know what are the aliases for each column.

Comment: Oh, I miss understood. I am updating it now!!!!

Comment: Please let me know if that is what you meant

Comment: Thank you for the advice Ryan! I am updating it now.

Comment: How many records are there from `a` only, after you remove the left join with `b`? (but keep the where clause and group by expression)

Comment: @sebas in the query without the left join, there are 301 rows for a

Answer (score 0):

A LEFT JOIN should return records with NULL values. The docs at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html say this about LEFT JOIN:

> If there is no matching row for the right table in the ON or USING
>   part in a LEFT JOIN, a row with all columns set to NULL is used for
>   the right table. You can use this fact to find rows in a table that
>   have no counterpart in another table

If the values of MID, FBID or TID are invalid, all of those records will be returned anyway (13 million, I suppose). INNER JOIN, or just "JOIN" will exclude records that do not match.

Before the quote above, in general about the ON clause:

> The conditional_expr used with ON is any conditional expression of the
>   form that can be used in a WHERE clause. Generally, you should use the
>   ON clause for conditions that specify how to join tables, and the
>   WHERE clause to restrict which rows you want in the result set.

Comment: JOIN or INNER JOIN does product the right results, when results are found.

When there is nothing found for a particular post, it does not return that post.

Running the same query with JOIN will not product the 2747 rows from column posts. For a new user, using JOIN will always product empty results.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. INNER JOIN will exclude the records that do not match, while LEFT JOIN will include records that do not match in the "right" table, in this case table "b". What is your expected output? Do you really need the additional items in the ON clause that do not compare the two tables, just look at the values in table b?

Comment: I think I have to compare them this way because the column names aren't the same? I have just updated the question with a SHOW CREATE TABLE impressions

Comment: I have updated the question with the expected output.

Comment: Is table `entries` actually called `impressions`? What does `posts` look like? What do you mean the column names aren't the same? In which tables?

Comment: Yes, Entries is impressions. I'm sorry. There are actually two left joins in the whole query and I have tried to make it smaller to make it easier to understand. If I can get it to work with one, I should be able to get it working for both LEFT JOINS.

Comment: The other column I want to join is the exact same. impressions and entries are exactly the same

Answer (score 0):

After many "Oh I know what it must be"'s.. I figured it out!

To LEFT JOIN null rows, simply add OR b.id IS NULL to the ON statement.

```
 EXPLAIN
  SELECT a.*,
         COUNT(b.SID) AS mcount,
    MAX(b.time) AS mtime
  FROM posts a
  LEFT JOIN impressions b ON a.SID = b.SID
  AND b.time > '1444679848'
  AND ((b.MID = '3'
       OR b.FBID = '418'
       OR b.TID = '152')
       OR b.id IS NULL)
  WHERE a.pending != 1
    AND a.sponsor != '1'
    AND a.fbpost = '0'
    AND a.roundup = '0'
    AND a.404 != '1'
    AND a.hide = '0'
    AND a.END >= '2015-10-22'
    AND a.added >= '2015-10-12'
    AND a.url_image > ''
    AND CHAR_LENGTH(a.states) < 80
    AND a.usa = '1'
  GROUP BY a.SID
  ORDER BY mcount DESC, (a.int_clicks + (a.int_views2b * 100)) DESC
```